# Words or text rolling over the action in beginning of films

Tags: production, credits, terminology

Is there a name for the rolling text, sometimes a prologue, in mid 20th c. movies? Often in westerns one would see on the screen a wagon train or stagecoach from above, with an intro or explanation in text rolling over the top.

Comment: Opening scroll?

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D. I didn't know the english name for this technique, so I looked up and learned something :) Turned it into an answer FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

It's called (for the most iconic of all) [Opening Crawl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_opening_crawl) or [Opening Scroll](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OpeningScroll):

> As the name implies, this is a text scroll that passes over (or into) the screen, supplying all relevant information with minimal impact on the movie's running time or budget. A variation is to have the text fade up and then fade down, but this is something that shouldn't go on for too long due to being terribly dull to watch.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I wanted.... "opening crawl" .... great term.